# Can't start emulator: "Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1024M too high for your system. Reducing to maximum supported size 0M"

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, intel, haxm

I believe it's because I've updated my SDK and tools, without updating HAXM.  Unfortunately I don't have admin rights on this machine and need help figuring out how to get the emulator working without updating HAXM.  Any ideas?  Downgrading the SDK?  Maybe getting the new HAXM is the only option to progress forward?

```
9:55 AM Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1024M too high for your system. Reducing to maximum supported size 0M

9:55 AM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not low in available RAM? Have you tried to restart the computer and launch only the emulator to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Seen this happen on more than one machine after updating.  It's a Mac with 16 GB, has been rebooted, and plenty of RAM available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalled HAXM and back in business.  I think some configuration was corrupt when I tried to update HAXM and then couldn't complete from the SDK manager since I didn't have admin rights.  Reinstalling the old version of HAXM seems to have got things working again.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem. I've been looking for days to solve this problem. reinstalling HAXM or the emulator didn't help. You've got any other ideas?

Comment: Not sure why mine started working.  The only thing I could guess was it was related to HAXM.  I had rebooted, made sure everything was up-to-date in the SDK manager, and still wasn't having luck.  Suddenly it started working.

Comment: Also, check if you have multiple emulators in your path, and where you're running from.  When I try to launch from another directory, and the emulator isn't in the path, I get a Qt library not found error.  FYI, I've also updated to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2

Answer (score 0):

I had to 
1) Uninstall HAXM and Android Emulator (in SDK manager)
2) Restart computer
3) Re-install HAXM and Android Emulator